# Android - Access Servlet AsyncPost task response from fellow classes

Tags: java, android, json, servlets, android-studio

I have an app connected to a `Java Servlet backend` by means of an AsyncPost task. The task returns a String to the client representing a json object serialized with `Gson`.

It works almost fine, the problem is that I'm unable to access the Servlet response message from the class instantiating the call to the `ServletPostAsyncTask`: `ListViewPrenota.class`. 
The project is structured as follows:

Both within the Servlet and the Client I created the two classes, `Tour.class` and `Tours.class` to store my data:

Tour class:

```
public class Tour {
  // some simple int/string/list fields
}
```

Tours class:

```
public class Tours {
  private List<Tour> tours;
  // ...
}
```

On Client side, in a `ServletPostAsyncTask.class`, I receive the aforementioned Gson object within `doInBackGround()`. Within `onPostExecute()` I deserialize it, this way:

```
class ServletPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void,     String> {
    private Context context;
    Tours tours;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
     //connect to Servlet and get the serialized Gson object
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonResponse) {
        tours = (new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, Tours.class));
    }
}
```

Now, from `ListViewPrenota.class` in Client I am calling the `ServletPostAsyncTask`:

```
ServletPostAsyncTask s = new ServletPostAsyncTask();
s.execute(new Pair<Context, String>(ListViewPrenota.this, "tours"));
Tours ttours = s.tours;
Tour tour = ttours.getTours().get(0);
```

Problem: I receive a `java.lang.NullPointerException` pointing to `Tour tour = ttours.getTours().get(0);`

What is the reasong preventing me to access the newly received Tours object from other classes than `ServletPostAsyncTask`?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you are thinking that code runs serially, if you want to use stuff returned from the `AsycTask` you need to use it in `onPostExecute` or have a callback that sends the data after it is done

```
doInBackground(){
//do heavy work
}

onPostExecute(Data data){
//handle data
//send data via interface to activity or class that needs the data
//or just put everything that needs the data in here
}
```

Comment: Ok, however, I am filling my Tours tours object within `onPostExecute`, how this is different from what you meant?
By callback do you mean a getter? I've tried that also but didn't work...
Moreover, if the code isn't running serially, how do I know when the async task is done and can send the data?

Comment: your `Tours ttours = s.tours;` is not filled by the time your `onPostExecute` hits. all that code after you call `execute` immediately runs, it does not wait

Comment: they way to go is do what you need to do in the onPostExecute

Comment: Ok, but I got what you said, and I have done what I need to do inside `onPostExecute`: it actually fills my Tours object, the problem is that it does it too late as you suggested. How can I sync the whole process? Or you mean that it is not possible to pass objects from an Async task to the other classes ?

Comment: correct you cannot pass objects directly from an asynctask, you need to use an `interface` to create a callback when it is finished that sends the objects to the interface callback

Comment: Let me understand what you said: 1. the Interface creates the callback when it is finished, 2. after creation the callback sends objects... to the interface's callback.
Why to the callback?

Comment: Thanks! Read my answer, is it close to what you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it works. Here's what I was able to come up with:

Callback interface:

```
interface CallBack {
    void callBackMethod(Tours tours);//do job
}
```

Caller class:

```
class ServletPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Tours, String>{
    private Context context;
    Tours tours;
    public ListViewPrenota listViewPrenota;
    public ServletPostAsyncTask(ListViewPrenota listView){
        this.listViewPrenota = listView;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
        //communicate with Servlet and get a HttpResponse
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonResponse) {
        tours = (new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, Tours.class));

        //the callback starts a thread updating the UI in ListViewPrenota
        listViewPrenota.callBackMethod(tours);
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Connected. \nTours size: "+ tours.getTours().size(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

The callback interface's implementation within ListViewPrenota:

```
public class ListViewPrenota extends FragmentActivity implements CallBack{
    private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;
    private Runnable viewOrders;
    private TourAdapter m_adapter;
    ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Tour> m_tours =null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_prenota);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    m_tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();

    m_adapter = new TourAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, m_tours);
    listView.setAdapter(m_adapter);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //pulsante drawer
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);      //pulsante dietro

    ServletPostAsyncTask spat = new ServletPostAsyncTask(ListViewPrenota.this);
    String status = spat.getStatus().toString();
    spat.execute(new Pair<Context, String>(ListViewPrenota.this,"tours"));
}

public void callBackMethod(final Tours tours){
    System.out.println("I've been called back");
    viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getOrders(tours);
        }
    };
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            ListViewPrenota.this,
            "Please wait...",
            "Retrieving data ...",
            true);
}

public void getOrders(Tours tours){
    try{
        m_tours = new ArrayList<>();
        m_tours.addAll(tours.getTours());

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Log.i("ARRAY", "" + m_tours.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
    }
    //add tours to the adapter
    runOnUiThread(returnRes);
}
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(m_tours != null && m_tours.size() > 0){
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0;i<m_tours.size();i++)
                m_adapter.add(m_tours.get(i));
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

If there's a better way to do it I accept further suggestions. 
In the mean time, thank you very much